# CakePHP: Use Inflector Class over whole array

Tags: php, cakephp, slug, inflector

I need to use `Inflector::slug()` over all results fetched from my database, which are, of course, retrieved in an array. Is it possible somehow, or I'll need to loop each result and slugify it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `array_map()` function might do what you need (although it assumes a simple indexed array).

```
array_map( 'Inflector::slug', $your_result )
```

If you're looking at something more complex, CakePHP's `Set` utility class may be helpful in a multi-step implementation.

I haven't tried this in a CakePHP context (i.e. mapping through a CakePHP class method), but I can't think of any reason it wouldn't work off the top of my head. Maybe it'll at least get you started.

Comment: Wouldn't this convert array values to slugs? What about converting case of keys?

Comment: Maybe a variant? Something like `array_map('Inflector::slug', array_keys($your_array))`?

Comment: Yeah but that would return a new array consisting of numeric keys, and the values would be slugified keys of the initial array. I think the best way to do this would be to loop through the array and make the changes necessary. Ugly, but efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the array you can use `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive`.

Something like this should work.

This is for 5.3+;

```
array_walk_recursive($posts, function(&$value) {
    $value = Inflector::slug($value);
});
```

If you wanted to limit it to a certain field you could also do something like this:

```
array_walk_recursive($posts, function(&$value, $key) {
if ($key == 'title') {
    $value = Inflector::slug($value);
  }
});
```

I haven't used Cake in a while but like Rob Wilkerson said, you might find that the `Set` class could make lighter work of this.